# Can't add to arraylist from onClickListener

Tags: java, android, arraylist, onclicklistener

I am trying to add an ArrayList inside of another ArrayList but i always get this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

The problem seems to be the OnClickListener or the Dialog because this error does not happen in the OnCreateView().
Here is my code :

```
public class CoordsFragment extends Fragment {
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> AllCoords = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    public FloatingActionButton fab;
    public Dialog dialog;
    public Button cancel;
    public Button create;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_coords, container, false);

        mainLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_coords_main_layout);

        ArrayList<String> arr;
        arr = new ArrayList<String>();

        /*the 3 arr.add doesn't work because the views "name", "x" and "y" are null here but if i replace 
        them with normal strings it works. this is just for the exemple*/
        arr.add(name.getText().toString());
        arr.add(x.getText().toString());
        arr.add(y.getText().toString());
        //AllCords.add(arr); causes no error here
        AllCoords.add(arr);

        fab = view.findViewById(R.id.plus_fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fabClick();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void fabClick() {



        dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_coords, null);
        dialog.setContentView(dialogView);

        create = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.coords_dialog_create);
        create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialogCreate();
            }
        });

        cancel = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.coords_dialog_cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialogCancel();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }



    public void dialogCreate() {
        dialog.dismiss();
        ArrayList<String> arr;
        arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr.add(name.getText().toString());
        arr.add(x.getText().toString());
        arr.add(y.getText().toString());
        //AllCoords.add(arr); causes the error here
        AllCoords.add(arr);
    }

    public void dialogCancel() {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }



}
```

I didn't manage to find a working solution for me. Maybe i shouldn't use an ArrayList for this code, so if you have a solution that replace the ArrayList i'm fine with it.
Thank you in advance for answers and sorry in advance for my potential bad english.

Comment: Generally, it is not a good idea to use a static field to pass data between a dialog and other parts of your app, because dialogs may be automatically re-created by Android if it had to destroy it while it was shown. For example, you rotate the device, Android destroys and creates again the activity and the dialog, but the data is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found myself where the problem was, thanks all for your answers but the problem isn't in the code i sent.

So the problem was that i was getting an ArrayList from sharedPreferences(using gson) and saving it in AllCoords. but if no data was saved in sharedPreferences, the ArrayList would always be null.

I'm sorry for wasting your time, it was impossible to find the solution with the code i sent.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize `name`, `x` and `y` before use them. I have not found the initializations of variables in the code.

Comment: ops i removed the initialisation of these variables by error in my code but the problem isn't there

Comment: How do you initialize the variables?

Comment: i do it like this: name = dialog.findViewById(R.id.name);

Comment: I think you should use `name = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.name);` or `name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);`. I dont know where you have these variable initialization